# How to access Polymer variables from outside Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, polymer, tinymce-4

I have this element which contains a tinymce html editor as an iframe. It works perfectly when sending the text data to the editor via url parameter. However, the size of url parameter are limited and I need to find a way to send the text data to the iframe.

Inside the iframe I can call window.parent.getTemplate().
The function getTemplate gets only found when its inside a normal javascript tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTemplate(){
        return 'xyz';
  }
</script>
```

If its inside the polymer script, it doesn't get found.

**My question:**

How can I access the Polymer variable 'emailtemplate' from inside the getTemplate() function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTemplate(){
        return 'xyz';
  }
</script>

<polymer-element name="crm-emailtemplate-editor" extends="core-overlay" backdrop attributes="emailtemplate">

  <template>

    <core-scroll-header-panel flex>
        <div class="core-header" horizontal layout reverse center>
            <core-toolbar>
                <core-icon-button icon="close" on-tap="{{closeTapped}}"></core-icon-button>
                    <paper-input label="Name" value="{{emailtemplate.et_name}}"></paper-input>
                <core-icon-button icon="save" on-tap="{{saveTapped}}"></core-icon-button>
            </core-toolbar>
          </div>

          <div id="content" class="content">

            <iframe id="editor" src="html-editor.php"></iframe>

          </div>

        </core-scroll-header-panel>

  </template>


  <script>
    Polymer({
        publish:{
            emailtemplate:{}    
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thats the iframe where the getTemplate() function is called at init.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
    image_list: "../image_list.php",

    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function(args) {
            // var htmlcontent = getQueryVariable('content');
            // tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(decodeURIComponent(htmlcontent));
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceFullScreen');

            // get emailtemplate content to display
            var tpl = window.parent.getTemplate();
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tpl);
        });

        ed.on('change', function(e) {
            console.log('change event', e);
            var htmlcontent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            document.getElementById("htmlContent").innerHTML = htmlcontent;

        });

        ed.on('NodeChange', function(e){
            console.log('change event', e);
            var htmlcontent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            document.getElementById("htmlContent").innerHTML = htmlcontent;
         });
    }
});

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  // GET Parameter
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
        <textarea id="editor" name="content" style="width:100%">Easy!</textarea>
        <htmlcopy id="htmlContent"></htmlcopy>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your trouble is just because you don't wait Polymer is ready. You have to add a listener on the `polymer-ready` event before to hope to use safely the Polyfill.

[Get a Polymer component property value from outside the element example](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2yDkM).

*EDIT* :

I misread, I'm sorry. So, you can use the above way I said and define the getTemplate method like a Window method.

```
// Your external method.
var getTemplate = function(){
  var editor = document.querySelector("crm-emailtemplate-editor");
  return editor.emailtemplate;
}
```

I forked my previous Plunk

[Get an element property Polymer from an iframe who is inside the element itself.](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1daAy)

Comment: Great thanks!!! But I'd like to call getTemplate from the iFrame. (I've added the code above). The iFrame is in crm-emailtemplate-editor.html which itself is in crm-template-overview.html

Comment: Thanks again! But it could not find the editor with document.querySelector("crm-emailtemplate-editor"); I ended up using the local storage to send the data to the iframe.. Don't know if its the best solution, but it works..

Comment: @JFathi Have you tried to define the getTemplate method when Polymer is ready (into the callback "polymer-ready") ? Have you tried retrieve the element by an ID ? I'm surprised and sorry. If you want remove the local storage usage I can look this part of your code with you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the localStorage to send data to the iframe.

```
<core-localstorage name="ninja_localStorage-emailtemplate" value="{{emailtemplate.et_content}}"></core-localstorage>
```

and reading from the iframe:

```
var contentFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('ninja_localStorage-emailtemplate');
```